# D3.js or EXT js for data visualization and why?

Tags: javascript, extjs, d3.js, data-visualization

I am trying to learn D3 JS and how it can be applied in current application.I am new to this application.

While going through the application I found that there is already a feature providing data visualization in the form of graphs using EXT Js charts.

Could anybody help me understand the advantage of data visualization using ext js over D3 JS and is there any reason for going with one over other? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExtJS is a commercial web app framework for many things including data visualization. D3.js is an open source low level library for creating svg-based charts.

The first question you need to figure out is if you only want charts or all the features that come with ExtJS.

If you just want to draw standard charts (bar, line, area, pie etc.) you may consider using [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/), google charts, or a higher level library on top of d3.js such as [nvd3.js](http://nvd3.org/) or [Rickshaw](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/) since they are easier to use. Otherwise if you want a very non-standard and customized chart, d3.js is very powerful for implementing any possible kind of visualization.

Answer (score 0):

D3 is just for visualization, ExtJS is a full framework that hast a lot of other components (grids, windows, layouts, etc...).

Also ExtJS doesn't get well with other libraries, since it overrides several things in the global CSS.

Therefore, if you have a full page that has more than just graphs... feel free to use ExtJS for the whole page, but if you already have something else on the page, then go for D3.